Is there an analytical solution for this summation?
In a problem I've been doing I ended up with this summation:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
This converges to a negative number, but I can't for the life of me find an analytical solution for it (in terms of some set of other well known constants or as an output from some combination of elementary functions) and was wondering if anyone on stack exchange had any tips.
Or, if you think there is no such solution, I'd also appreciate it if you notified me.

See A352619 in the OEIS. It doesn't look like there's a nice closed form.

We can begin by using the Taylor series for the inverse tangent.
$$
\tan^{-1}(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}
$$
Plugging this into the infinite sum we get the following.
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \left( -\frac{1}{n} + \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\frac{1}{n^{2k+1}} \right)
$$
The $k=0$ value cancels the $1/n$ term. Then by interchanging the order of sumation we are left with the following.
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+1}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^{2k+1}}
$$
We can recognize the sum over $n$ as the Riemann Zeta function.
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+1} \zeta (2k+1)
$$
This can also be expressed as the imaginary part of this sum.
$$
\Im \sum^{\infty}_{k=2} \frac{i^{k}}{k} \zeta (k)
$$
We can then consider the following generating function.
$$
G(z) = \sum^{\infty}_{k=2} \frac{z^{k}}{k} \zeta (k)
$$
Of which our sum would then be equal to $\Im(G(i))$. We can then use the following fact of the Taylor series of the digamma function.
$$
\psi(z+1) = -\gamma - \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}(-z)^k \zeta (k+1)
$$
Where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. We can then therefore find that...
$$
G'(z) = -\psi (1-z) - \gamma \quad \rightarrow \quad G(z) = \operatorname{Log}(\Gamma (1-z))-\gamma z
$$
We therefore can find analytical representation of your sum using the definition of the principle branch of the complex $\operatorname{Log}$.
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n} = \operatorname{Arg}(\Gamma(1-i))-\gamma
$$
There is no known representation of the argument of the Gamma function in the complex plane using a finite series of elementary functions. I think this is as close as you will be able to get to the kind of answer you're looking for. However, if an approximate awnser is acceptable $- \gamma / 2$ is a very good approximation only under estimating the actual value by $0.01303$. I tried to figure out why this is a good approximation but I wasn't able to find a good explanation and I only came about it via guessing.

Ah, that's unfortunate because this series shows up in the angle of the complex number $i!$ (Which is what I was trying to find an analytic expression for), so sadly this looks like it would be a somewhat circular definition for me.
I got as far as $i!=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi}}}e^{-i\left(\gamma+\xi\right)}$
Where $\xi=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

Using that somewhat surprisingly effective aproximation of $-\gamma  /2$ for the expression you just commented you get a square modulus error of $4.62\times10^{-6}$. Wich is a very good aproximation.

In your second equation $(-1)^k/k$ should be $(-1)^k/(2k+1)$, right (?)

Since we know that
$$\int \Bigg(\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\Bigg)\,dn=n\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \log
   \left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ we can try the simplest form of Euler-MacLaurin summation
This would give
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\right)\sim \frac{12529}{26880}-\frac{\pi }{8}-\frac{\log (2)}{2}=-0.280713$$ which is in $0.87$% relative error.
The next level would give
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\right)\sim \frac{1220281}{2661120}-\frac{\pi }{8}-\frac{\log (2)}{2}=-0.273164$$
But, for sure, the pure beauty (already reported by @Aidan R.S.) is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\right)=- \Big(\gamma +\arg (i\, \Gamma (i))\Big)$$ that is to say
$$-\gamma-\frac i 2 \,\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (1-i)}{\Gamma(1+i)}\right)$$
